# ServerVersion: Invalid Operation. The connection is closed

Tags: sql-server-2008, wampserver

I have a workstation with Windows 7 (IIS 6.0), MS SQL Server 2008, Visual Studio 2008. 
My SQL Server Management Studio works fine. But I am not able to get a connection through any of my projects in VS2008 or VS2010
Code I am using:

```
        Dim _SqlConnectionString As String = "Data Source=" + Environment.MachineName + "\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=true;"
        Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(_SqlConnectionString) 
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cn.Open()
```

**The error I get is inside ServerVersion property of my SqlConnection: Invalid Operation. The connection is closed**

This problem appeared after installing wamp server & php. What should I do? Is there any conflict? I made my wamp server to listen to other port than this of IIS, but what about SQL Server? Why I cannot connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once before.
The one day the Visual Studio Windows Application that I ran successfully through the code in debug mode was working perfectly and did what it needed to do. The very next day, it just did not make a connection, giving me this error: ServerVersion: Invalid Operation. The connection is closed.
Funny enough, I used a SQL User that had permissions on this Database as my user to connect to the database.
The reason why I got this message, is because that specific SQL user I used to make my connection, was Disabled at that time. I Enabled it again and everything just started working again.

It might be something small like this or maybe a Windows Service that is not started.
Personal Experiance